# Formula to calculate the sensitivity of a bond to curve steepening

Tags: fixed-income, yield-curve, duration

https://github.com/jerryxyx/TreasuryFutureTrading/blob/master/README.pdf

On page 2 of the pdf above, the sensitivity of a bond to increases in the slope of the curve, is given as $\ln(T)$, where $T$ is the maturity of the bond.

- Is this relationship exact, i.e. derived from the bond pricing equation, or simply a rule of thumb?
- If it is simply a rule of thumb, does anyone know how well it works in practice?

On page 4 the sensitivity of the bond to the slope is defined as $S\ln(T)$ (unfortunately $S$ is not defined), they say then that this expression can be approximated by $D \ln(D)$, where D is the bond's duration.

- Does anyone know what S could stand for?
- How well do one of both of there expressions on p4 work in capturing the sensitivity of the bond to changes in curve steepness?

Thanks Baz

Answer (score 2):

I cannot quite follow that ansatz, maybe we do not agree on the definition of slope:

Let $r(\tau)\equiv a+b\tau$ be the discount rate curve for a continuously compounded rate as a function of the time to maturity $\tau$. The discount factor for a cash flow with time to maturity $\tau$ is $D(\tau)=e^{-r(\tau)\tau}=e^{-a\tau-b\tau^2}$. The sensitivity of the discount factor w.r.t. the slope parameter $b$ is

$$
\frac{\partial D(\tau)}{\partial b}=-\tau^2D(\tau)
$$

which scales with $\tau^2$. The same holds true for a bond as a series of discounted cash flows; furthermore, the sensitivity is proportional to the negative of the bond's convexity, $\frac{\partial D(\tau)}{\partial b}\propto -\frac{\partial^2 D(\tau)}{\partial r^2}$